# SonarQube complaining that Logger is not covered by unit test

Tags: sonarqube

my company started using SonarQube.
I am seeing that it complains that code which contains logger is not covered by unit test, for example:

```
LOGGER.debug("All sub merchants have been evicted from cache.");
```

How do we cover by unit test logger?

One more code sample:

```
    @Override
    @TriggersRemove(removeAll = true, cacheName = TRUNCATE_PARAMS_CACHE_NAME,
            keyGenerator = @KeyGenerator(name = CACHE_KEY_GENERATOR,
                    properties = @Property(name = "includeMethod", value = "false")))
    public void evictAll() {
        LOGGER.info("Evicting all truncation candidates");
    }
}
```

Sonar marked the line where LOGGER appears as not covered by unit tests.

Answer (score -1):

Sonar is complaining about not logging the exact exception.

This should make the warning go:

```
LOGGER.debug("All sub merchants have been evicted from cache.", e);
```

Comment: i have this piece of code, which is marked also as uncovered, i guess this is not it.   } catch (DataAccessException e) {
            // Mechanical error occurred.
            LOGGER.error("Error occurred querying submerchant data.", e);
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

Comment: Could you please post the exact Sonar message? The code sample would also help.

Comment: Do you use JaCoCo with Sonar? Because this looks like code coverage warning, which would mean that you should cover that branch/exception in one of your unit tests.

Comment: i am not sure about JaCoCo, but the main question was how exactly am i expected to cover lines with junit that include logger?

Comment: Are you sure the message is about the logger and not the chunk of code in the catch clause not covered by unit tests? 

Could you try putting any other line of code instead of the logger one and check whether the warning is still present. 

In order to cover it by unit test you'll have to cause whatever part of your code can throw that exception to actually throw it and validate the outcome. 

Could you clarify whether you're asking to help you with covering the exception in the unit test or you don't use unit tests at all and would like to learn about them?

Comment: we are using unit tests, i will try adding tests and see if the warning goes away. thanks.